# Does this matrix exist (eigenvalue given)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Does $A\in R^{3\times3}$ with first row $\pmatrix {1&2&3} $ exist (?), if...

$A$ can be inverted and

one of its eigenvalues is zero

Answer (score 6):

If $A$ has an eigenvalue of zero, then it necessarily cannot be inverted (that is, $A$ is singular). So, the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. A square matrix is invertible iff zero is **not** one of its eigenvalues, as otherwise its kernel's dimension (the matrix's nullity) is bigger than zero